# Reading ColdFusion file in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, coldfusion, c#-2.0

I am trying to build generic code in C# (console), which can read a ColdFusion file and list the tables embedded. The .cfm file has many tables and a lot of sub queries. Below is dummy example:

```
<cfquery  >
    SELECT a, b
    FROM   table t,
           table t2
    WHERE  count > 0
</cfquery>
<cfquery >
    SELECT a, b
    FROM
        (SELECT a, b
         FROM   
             (SELECT a, b 
              FROM   table x,y)
</cfquery>
```

For the time being I am trying to parse the .cfm file using substring and splitting the string with ("From") but that is not giving me effective results. Can someone help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? At a guess, assuming the page *only* contains cfml query tags (not cfscript) you might have better luck searching for `<cfquery>` tags and extracting the contents. Then running it through a SQL parser. but  recommending a tool for that is probably off-topic for S.O.

Comment: What is the ultimate problem that you're trying to solve? What is being done with the table names? One other concern: What if the query is using proper JOINs instead of the comma syntax? You'll miss those tables. Honestly, if you're looking to rebuild queries based on what's there, I would highly recommend just biting the bullet and refactoring those queries.

Comment: Split by <cfquery> tags to FROM tags. Then replace </cfquery>.